# Flutter ListWheelScrollView

Tags: flutter

My *ListWheelScrollView* sort of scrolls randomly and lands between values, i searched for quite a while but didnt find a way to handle it. Does somebody know a fix for this?

```
new ListWheelScrollView(itemExtent: _screenHeight * 0.08,
                        clipToSize: true,
                        controller: widget.minuteController,
                        onSelectedItemChanged: (int value){
                          minute = value;
                        },
                        children: buildMinutesList(_screenWidth),
)
```

screenshot (with 2 wheels): [https://ibb.co/dwjeMU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBz0J.png)

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but your question seems pretty unclear. Do you want the full code for a wheel like this? And what do you want a fix for?

Answer (score 0):

I think this package is exactly what you're trying to achieve: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/numberpicker

Comment: Thanks, thats going to work. Well im trying to use as few third-party-Libraries as possible in my project, but if i cant find another solution i might have to use this.

I'm going to accept this answer if noone else finds a way to archive this without using another library.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may be late for you, using `physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics()` should be fine, for future people.